# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/Ultralytics'

Tags: python, docker, windows-10, yolo

I try to run video recognition with yolov3 in my python backend made with django.

I made all the instalation in the requirements.txt but when I try to execute the detect.py script I have this error:

[image]

I find 0 information on this problem on google. (just this https://blog.csdn.net/tanvanyo/article/details/120800075)

I work on Windows 10, Docker Desktop 4.9.0.

I just do git clone, docker build .

I try to create /tmp/Ultralytics directory but nothing works...

Do you have an idea why I have this issue ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Hi, have you checked the permissions of the folder? I would appreciate the output of `ls -l /tmp/Ultralytics` from inside the container.

Comment: @Anton I just retry with good permission `drwxrwxrwx 1 django-user django-user     4096 Nov  3 15:05  tmp`